# Common authentication interface for multiple applications

Tags: architecture, saml-2.0, okta

My customer wants to develop several small web applications, each with its own purpose. They want to provide a common interface for external users to login using 2-3 third party identity providers like Okta, that support SAML authentication. Once the user logs in, the applications he is authorized to access should be listed as icons and he should be able to enter an application by clicking on the icon.

Even if there is no interface for listing accessible applications for the user, the customer is fine with having a framework that will force the user to authenticate when he accesses the URL of an application directly and allow access only if the user is authorized.

This sounds like a common requirement of many organizations that want to expose their applications to external or internal users with proper authorization controls. Is there a common pattern/framework to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET world, decorating a method in the application with:

[Authorize]

forces the user to authenticate with the configured IDP.

Using e.g. ADFS as an IDP, the user sees a Home Realm Discovery page that shows the user all the IDP available for the user to authenticate on.

In Azure AD, all the applications that a user has permissions to use appear in:

myapps.microsoft.com

There are similar "patterns" for other providers but I'm not aware of any formal specification.